# Terraform Reference to undeclared module No module call named "security-groups" is declared in the root module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cloud

**Here is my project tree which is hosted on a github private repo**

```
├── deployment
│   ├── security-groups
│   │   ├── data.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   ├── providers.tf
│   │   ├── sg-eks.tf
│   │   ├── terraform.auto.tfvars
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── vpc
│       ├── data.tf
│       ├── locals.tf
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       ├── providers.tf
│       ├── terraform.auto.tfvars
│       └── variables.tf
├── modules
│   ├── security-groups
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── vpc
│       ├── data.tf
│       ├── locals.tf
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       └── variables.tf
```

**module/vpc/outputs.tf**

```
  output "vpc_id" {
    description = "The VPC ID"
    value       = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  }


output "public_subnets" {
  description = "List of IDs of public subnets"
  value       = values(aws_subnet.public)[*].id
}

output "private_subnets" {
  description = "List of IDs of private subnets"
  value       = values(aws_subnet.private)[*].id
}
```

**and the deployment/vpc/outputs.tf**

```
output "vpc_id" {
  description = "The VPC ID"
  value       = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

output "public_subnets" {
  description = "List of IDs of public subnets"
  value       = module.vpc.public_subnets
}

output "private_subnets" {
  value       = module.vpc.private_subnets
}
```

**plan and apply work but when I do the same for another module:**

**modules/security-groups/output.tf**

```
output "security_group_arn" {
  description = "The ARN of the security group"
  value       = values(aws_security_group.sg)[*].arn
}
```

**deployment\security-groups/output.tf**

```
output "security_group_arn" {
  description = "The ARN of the security group"
  value       = module.security-groups.security_group_arn
}
```

**I get Reference to undeclared module No module call named "security-groups" is declared in the root module.
I call on this module in my source "/barak-kalai/terraform-infra.git//modules/security-groups?ref=dev" this works if I plan without the outputs so the module is in place**

I'm expecting that apply will produce outputs that I can later use in other module
The vpc output is working and I call on it in the terraform cloud remote tfstate

Comment: `?ref=dev` means you're strictly referencing the code on your branch named `dev`. Does your dev branch contain all the code you expect?

Comment: None of the code snippets you've shared include a `module "security-groups"` block.

Answer (score 0):

The module name is defined in the root and i was using the file name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).